# Neo4j to grafana

Tags: neo4j, grafana

I want to present release data complexity which is associated with each node like at epic, userstory etc in grafana in form of charts but grafana do not support neo4j database.Is there any way Directly or indirectly to present neo4j database in grafana?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issues and found this question among others. From my research I cannot agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52382086/5823275) completely, so I felt I should point some things out, here.

Just to clarify: a graph database may seem structurally different from a relational or time series database, but it is possible to build Cypher queries that basically return graph data as tables with proper columns as it would be with any other supported data source. Therefore this sentence of the above mentioned answer:

> *So what you want to do is just not possible.*

is not absolutely true, I'd say.

The actual problem is, there is no datasource plugin for Neo4j available at the moment. You would need to [implement one on your own](https://grafana.com/docs/plugins/developing/datasources/), which will be a lot of work (as far as I can see), but I suspect it to be possible. For me at least, this will be too much work to do, so I won't use any approach to read data directly from Neo4j into Grafana.

**As a (possibly dirty) workaround** (in my case), a service will regularly copy relevant portions of the Neo4j graph into a relational database (or a time series database, if the data model is sufficiently simple for that), which Grafana is aware of (see [datasource plugins](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins?type=datasource)), so I can query it from there. This is basically the replication idea also given in the above mentioned answer. In this case you obviously end up with at least 2 different database systems and an additional service, which is not so insanely great, but at the moment it seems to be the quickest way to resolve the problem with the missing datasource plugin. Maybe this is applicable in your case, too.

Answer (score 0):

Using [neo4j's graphite metrics](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/metrics/expose/#metrics-graphite) you can actually configure data to be sent to grafana, and from there build whichever dashboards you like.

Up until recently, graphite/grafana wasn't supported, but it is now (in the recent 3.4 series releases), along with prometheus and other options.

Comment: the question is not about metrics ... but the data in Neo4j

Answer (score 0):

**Update July 2021**

There is a new plugin called [Node Graph Panel](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/visualizations/node-graph/) (currently in beta) that can visualise graph structures in Grafana. A prerequisite for displaying your graph is to make sure that you have an API that exposes two [data frames](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/plugins/data-frames/), one for nodes and one for edges, and that you set `frame.meta.preferredVisualisationType = 'nodeGraph'` on both data frames. See the [Data API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/visualizations/node-graph/#data-api) specification for more information.

So, one option would be to setup an API around your Neo4j instance that returns the nodes and edges according to the specifications above. Note that I haven't tried it myself (yet), but it seems like a viable solution to get Neo4j data into Grafana.

Answer (score -1):

Grafana support those databases, but not Neo4j :  Graphite, InfluxDB, OpenTSDB, Prometheus, Elasticsearch, CloudWatch

So what you want to do is just not possible.

You can replicate your Neo4j data inside of those database, but the datamodel is really different ... (timeseries vs graph).

If you just want to have some charts, you can use Apache Zeppeline for that.